# When to put a verb ahead of its doer?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, nouns, word-order, syntactic-analysis

I have read this at the [Science.com](http://news.sciencemag.org/sciencenow/2012/11/early-humans-handed-down-toolmak.html), and it's in the second line of the last paragraph.

> A bow and arrow or an atlatl allows users to attack prey—and enemies—from a safer 
>   distance than **does** an ordinary spear.

I would have put it this way: A bow and arrow or an atlatl allows users to attack prey—and enemies—from a safer distance than an ordinary spear **does**.

So here are my questions:

1. Are both of the two sentences right?
2. When **can** I put the verb ahead of the noun? When is it a necessity?

Comment: The verb first actually sounds better to me, unfortunately I'm not really able to describe why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a particular property of the pro-verb *do* (and also *have*, when it is a pro-verb, and *be*).

When one of these auxiliaries is used to stand for a verb phrase which has just been mentioned, after a conjunction like *than* or *as*, the verb may precede the subject:

> He is going home now, as am I.
>
> I want this to end, as do they.

The inversion is not compulsory, and tends to be associated with more formal or literary language than the uninverted form (your no. 2):

> He is going home now, as I am.

There is a parallel with *So* used to mean *also*:

> So does he!

but in this case, the inversion is compulsory, as without it the meaning will change:

> So he does.

means either *and therefore he does (whatever)* or *I am surprised or appreciative that he does (whatever)* depending on the intonation; but it has no sense of *as well*.

Comment: There is this Germanic left-branching tendency to replicate items backwards at the end of a sentence. Tag questions work that way, don't they? Chuck Fillmore once mentioned "a party game in which people English as if it a verb-final language were to speak induced are."

Comment: @John Lawler: Haha - I like that one! I suppose it's horses for courses, but I'm glad the ordering in my native language doesn't force me to read that many words before I get to find out **what's happening** (i.e. - the verbs! :).

Comment: Me, too. But over half the languages in the world are standard SOV. It's a very stable configuration.

Comment: I was never a fan of [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). I'm surprised the fraction is "over half the languages in the world".

Comment: Now I think of it, other auxiliaries such as _can_ and _should_ show this pattern as well, though they're not common after _than_.